# Say time in 24 hour format

Tags: grammar

I've never seen in Chinese study materials that time could be said/written in 24 hour format. It is always in 12 hour format with addition of description like 早上, 下午... E.g.:

- 早上八点半
- 晚上九点四十五分

And never like:

- 二十一点四十五分

Is it ok to say/write time in 24 hour format?

Comment: Typically, only military, airport and train station use 24 hours format

Comment: 零点零一分钟：００：０１，十九点零四分，１９：０４，二十三点五十九分，２３：５９ famous song 零点零一分:https://www.google.com/search?q=%E9%9B%B6%E7%82%B9%E9%9B%B6%E4%B8%80%E5%88%86&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-ab

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's no problem to use either in practice, though people used 12 hour format more (because 6 is easier to say than 18 ). When being asked: 现在几点, I might answer either 6点半 or 18点30. 18点30 sounds a little bit formal or "verbose".